# Using Tor in a python script in Windows

Tags: windows, linux, python

I'm using the TorRequest library (https://github.com/erdiaker/torrequest) on Linux and it works fine, but I also need to run this script on Windows as well. In my distro, I installed only the **tor** package and it worked, I did not need the **TorBrowser**.

So that's my question. If I install TorBrowser on Windows, will my script work? Does it install together something like the "tor" package I mentioned that allows you to use the Tor network without having to use TorBrowser?

I'm not a Windows user, so the question may sound silly.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it should work fine, as long as you give it the right Control and SOCKS ports when you create the TorRequests instance, I.E.

```
 request = TorRequest(proxy_port = 9150, ctrl_port=9151)
```

Since it's using stem and you can specify alternative ports, this should work fine using Tor Browser without requiring a stand-alone `tor.exe` for it to launch.